# Node: run 2 sql queries at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, node-mssql

I have a simple api to communicate with my mobile app and i have some updates to do.

I want to make 2 updates at the same function (or th same route) but i dont know if its possible.

Here is the dboperation part:

```
async function updateCusto() {
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let updateCusto = await pool.request()
            .input('input_parameter1', sql.Int, CodOS)
            .input('input_parameter2', sql.Int, CodProduto)
            .query("update osproduto set custounit=produto.precocusto, valorunitario=produto.precosugerido from OSProduto INNER JOIN Produto ON OSProduto.CodProduto = Produto.Codigo  where codproduto=@input_parameter2 and codos=@input_parameter1")
           .query("Update OSProduto set sub=qtde*valorunitario where codos=@input_parameter1") //the second one, doenst work
        return updateCusto.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

and here is the route part:

```
router.route("/updateCusto").post((request, response) => {
    CodOS = request.body.CodOs;
    CodProduto = request.body.CodProduto;
    dboperations.updateCusto(CodOS, CodProduto).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        response.json("Update ok!");
    })
        .catch(error => response.json({ error }))
})
```

How can i do this? Is there a way to run the 2 updates on the same operation? Or do i need to create another operation to use on the same route, after the first update is made (and if so, how can i do that?).

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible, in fact I would do it as a transaction, this way if one of the queries fails a rollback would be made in order to preserve the state of your database.

Here are my suggestions:

1. Read about database transactions
2. Replace pure SQL with an ORM such as [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html) or [KnexJS](https://knexjs.org/#Transactions), it will help you to prevent errors by making queries calling methods such as `await OsProduto.update({ where: { id: 0 }}, newData);`